# Set cache handler at object level?

Tags: php, late-binding, late-static-binding

Say I have a base object, CacheObject:

```
abstract class CacheObject {
    protected static $handler = null;

    public static function setCacheHandler($handler) {
        static::$handler = $handler;
    }

    public static function getCacheHandler($handler) {
        return static::$handler;
    }
}

class A extends CacheObject {

}

class B extends CacheObject {

}

A::setCacheHandler('test');
var_dump(B::getCacheHandler());
```

B will give me "test", which I believe is because class A does not have it's own defined property $handler... so it is using the inherited one, shared by class B. Is this accurate?

Is there any way I can in fact have them set separately, without needing to declare $handler within every object?

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
public static function getCacheHandler($handler) { // No need to pass arg here
        return static::$handler;
    }
```

should be

```
public static function getCacheHandler() {
        return static::$handler;
    }
```

Comment: Indeed.. I had just copied it quickly in this example. But it doesn't answer my original question... :)